# Can't see any objects anymore

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, edit-mode

I went to hit <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to switch out of perspective mode but I accidentally hit another key. Now my scene looks like this:

[image]

All of the meshes are still there:

[image]

What can I do? I can upload the .blend if needed.

Comment: Did you checked the layers visibility ?

Comment: Is it possible you hit numpad `/` and you are in *Local view*? (pressing numpad `/` again will toggle it) If not, could you upload the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Polosson's help I discovererd that I was on a different layer.
For others with this problem make sure your layers looks like this

[image]

And not something like

[image]

Comment: You can also press `\`` (the key below the `Esc` key on most keyboards) to toggle all layers visible.