# Cannot see any object in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, shortcut

I can't remember what keys I pressed on the keyboard but I cannot see anything on the scene. I already checked the layers visibility, that wasn't the problem. 
I am using Blender 2.74 on a Mac, therefore no numpad.

I already checked this out:
[Can't see any objects anymore](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/cant-see-any-objects-anymore)

[image: Missing Objects]

This is what happened after I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image: Missing Objects 2]

Here's the file:

[image]

Comment: Your view seems of-centered. try pressing `Shift+`C` while the cursor is hovering the 3D viewport to center the view, see if that helps

Comment: I can see the grid now but still no mesh. I just added a cube and I can see the cube and the grid but nothing else

Comment: Well hard to tell without any more info. Could you edit your question and upload your blend file?

Comment: How do I upload a blend file?

Comment: You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Be sure to upload a as simple as possible blender file only with relevant data for the problem at hand, and pack all relevant external data before uploading. Then edit you question to add the link and be sure to poke a user in a comment with `@Username` when you do, so know and get a notification

Comment: What you see after you pressed `Shift`+`C` means that your cube, if you added it, is not in the center of scene, rather than somewhere else. If it's still selected, press `Shift`+`S` > *Selection To Cursor*. Your question is then related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/snap-entire-selection-to-the-3d-cursor-in-edit-mode

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1636" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1636/)                       @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your objects have invalid coordinates, and are positioned at infinity.
Don't know how that happened but the bottom line is Blender can't handle it so you can't see your objects.

You will probably have to manually place your objects again one by one, as no other methods seem to be working currently.

1. Go to the outliner
2. Set it to *Current Scene*
3. Select one of the objects from the list
4. Go to the 3D view
5. Open the properties tool shelf <kbd>N</kbd> key
6. Change the values for location from invalid values to `0,0,0`or anything else that suits you

[image: Invalid coordinates]

Changing for the parent of several objects seems to be enough though, for all others you will have to manually place them in the scene at correct positions again

Comment: It's working. I can see all the objects. Thank you so much. @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because I accidentally pressed something and everything except one object has disappeared.

I simply un-checked and checked the box which lays next to "Collection" and it showed up again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be because you set your Viewpoint Render Distance VERY low.

Select an Object you want to center your Viewpoint on Press "," on your Numpad to center your view.

Next in your "N" menu on the right side of your "3D View" set in the tab "View" your Clip: Start: 0.1 and End: 1000

This should resolve your Problem

Edit: To check if your Object are outside of your visible Area. Select an object of your by using the outliner window, by default top right.

Now you either can center your view on this object using the method above or press "space" in your "3D View" and type in "view selected" if this still does not work Check if your are in the right layer of Blender.

You can check this with the "20 Layer Buttons" in your "3D View's Toolbar"

An orange dot means this is the layer the item is in.
A grey one means there is an object but its not selected.

By pressing on the buttons you change your layer view press Shit + the ones you want to select multiple layers.

Comment: No, still can't see any mesh. I don't have a Numpad so I just pressed "," on my keyboard, does that make a difference?I just added a cube and I can see the cube and the grid but nothing else

Comment: The "," on your keyboard and numpad differ in blender.

Comment: I tried, still cannot see anything.@Blender Pony

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, I had a taurus mesh and a plane mesh and the taurus just disappeared, I got it back by clicking View at the bottom left hand corner and then when it brings up the menu I clicked view all and viola it came back. Don't forget to save!

Answer (score 0):

On the keyboard, press button <kbd>`</kbd> which is the Tilde key, and select *View Selected*